# Where do you develop Django applications?

Tags: django

Django newbie here. Where should one develop a django application?

Can it be on a different machine? For example I can develop it on my local machine and then copy it to a server machine?

Or should it be on the same machine where the Apache web server is running? If that's the case, when I start a new project to be developed, should I be outside of public_html directory?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For development of Django web application, Apache server is not required at all. Django has it's own in-built development server, which can be used for testing while you are developing. Doing `python manage.py runserver` invokes that exactly.

You can develop it in your local machine and once it is ready for deployment you can put it in the server machine with Apache properly configured.

Comment: Ok thank you. How would I make sure that the looks (css) of the app is the same as the main page?

Comment: It depends on how you use the CSS for your app.